# In the Ubuntu Software Center, how are apps promoted?

Tags: software-center, application-development

I have made a Kakuro game called Sukaro for Ubuntu 11.10 and its successfully published in the Software Center (Its a commercial app).

And so far, I have not seen any advertisements (on websites, etc) regarding Ubuntu applications. So I was wondering, if you want to promote your published app, what should you do? (Aside from the most obvious things like Tweeting, etc.)

What options does a software developer for Ubuntu has for promoting his/her applications? Are there any specific review sites or such?

I think this game I made should get some more attention because its the first game about Kakuro/Cross Sums games.  And still the only game available in that category.

Comment: WebUpd8 has lots of articles about GNU/Linux and Ubuntu software. Another one I can think of is OMG Ubuntu. If you look around you'll find a few blogs/sites that fit your criteria. About advertising you could use paid ads on social media sites.

Comment: Don't hope to advertise in the Software Center :)

Comment: @devius Thanks for the sites! I'll check them out.. And I think you should add your comment as an answer.

Comment: @rafalcieslak Of course! :)

Answer (score 3):

There is a wealth of information online about how to market apps that also applies to the Ubuntu Software Center. Some examples that are not bad after a few minutes searching are:

- http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/03/03/how-to-market-your-mobile-app/
- http://www.karelia.com/mac_indie_marketing/15_suggestions_marketing_iphone_application.html

Now the specific things for the Ubuntu Software Center:

1. Sukaro app has a entry in our web directory: https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/sukaro/
2. Some example download buttons you can use: [Top January Apps](http://developer.ubuntu.com/2012/02/top-10-ubuntu-app-downloads-for-january-2012/)
3. Obviously writing a great description and asking users for reviews can go a long way, also having it translated, have you reached out to our [Translation Team](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Translations/)?
4. Icon's can really make a difference, having ones in all the sizes ensures a good first impression.
5. Check your keywords for your App, does a user search find it from the homepage of apps.ubuntu.com or when you search in the Software Center client, what about Google?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! That really helps. And I have added all the icons possible as well as a description and tags. But what did you mean by "..what about Google.."?